# Is there any other way to increase the size of the dataset? say more than 500mb

Tags: analytics, analytics-cloud

It is mentioned in the UI that the SF Analytics dataset could be only of 500mb of size.

What if I am in need of a dataset larger than 500mb? Is there any other way to increase the input upload size of the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've asked three related Analytics Cloud questions. Have you looked at the following references: [Analytics Cloud External Data API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/), [Analytics Cloud Dashboard JSON Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/), [Analytics Cloud Explorer SAQL Reference (PILOT)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_eql.meta/bi_dev_guide_eql/), [Analytics Cloud Extended Metadata (XMD) Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_xmd.meta/bi_dev_guide_xmd/), [Analytics Cloud External Data Format Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_ext_data_format.meta/bi_dev_guide_ext_data_format/), [Salesforce1 Reporting REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/), [Salesforce1 Reporting Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_analytics.meta/workbook_analytics/), and this article [Salesforce Backup and Restore Essentials Part 1: Backup Overview, API Options and Performance](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_Backup_and_Restore_Essentials_Part_1?utm_campaign=LightningWeek&utm_source=Newsletter_031015&utm_medium=Chief_Editor&eid=singlesend)?

The External Data API will allow you to increase your dataset size up to as large as 40 GB.

Comment: side note: he's asking separate questions because he first asked 1 big questions with a lot of subquestions which were not all related.

Comment: Thank you for your input. With the questions all being about Analytics-Cloud, it seemed to me that at a minimum, the two about datasets were closely related and the other could have been asked with them. But that's just one person's opinion.