# Measure column does not render any value

Tags: analytics, analytics-cloud

I've uploaded a sample dataset and found that the options in Measure column does not render any value - say Sum, Average, Maximum, Minimum and Unique. What should I do to make them bring values for Dataset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any other way to increase the size of the dataset? say more than 500mb](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69144/is-there-any-other-way-to-increase-the-size-of-the-dataset-say-more-than-500mb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download your JSON to check that the column is set to numeric not text.