# Ways to download a dataset from SF

Tags: analytics, analytics-cloud

Consider an existing dataset in Salesforce Analytics Dashboard. Is there a way to download the dataset from SF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any other way to increase the size of the dataset? say more than 500mb](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69144/is-there-any-other-way-to-increase-the-size-of-the-dataset-say-more-than-500mb)

Comment: What is your goal in downloading? Are you trying to get the data from Wave or a Salesforce environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no export available for loaded datasets on Salesforce Analytics because when it is uploaded it is converted into a compressed proprietary format.

Comment: This has now changed: The dataset utility tool from Salesforce now allows you to download the results of a query on a dataset

Comment: When we tried out using the browser, it gave us "stream ended unexpectedly" error. But the command line worked perfectly. Link for the dataset utility is https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils. Thanks @Andrew Price for the awesome explanation on this. https://www.andrewprice.me/blog/2015/7/5/downloading-a-dataset-in-salesforce-analytics-cloud

Answer (score 1):

We can export data from Salesforce analytics dataset from wave labs.

Here is the link

https://wave-labs.herokuapp.com/

Steps: 
1) login into your environment 
2) open the https://wave-labs.herokuapp.com/ url in new tab.
3) select production/sandbox
4) select SAQL
5) Type your SAQL with all fields and run the query
6) In the result panel you will be able to see export option.
7) On clicking on export button, data will be downloaded in CSV file.
8) pls note that, for large dataset it won't work.
9) Cheers. If it resolve your query, pls don't forget to hit Vote button.

Regards,
Niteen